# Ansible sort output by numbers

Tags: ansible, jmespath

Im using Ansible 2.9 and i want to order msg devices by number, i have this msg :

```
msg:  "{{ facts['ansible_facts'] | to_json | from_json | json_query('ansible_net_interfaces[?starts_with(name,`pl2`)].name') | list| sort }}"
```

And i have this output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "pl2",
        "pl2.10",
        "pl2.100",
        "pl2.102",
        "pl2.11",
        "pl2.111" ] ...
```

How can i make it show the output like this :

```
"pl2",
"pl2.10",
"pl2.11",
"pl2.12" ] ...
```

And also how to catch the biggest pl2.* ? for example if the biggest number is pl2.250?
Thanks!

Comment: Write a filter. See [examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/version_filters/version_filters.py).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [How to sort version numbers in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025894/how-to-sort-version-numbers-in-ansible), however the most valuable answer from there, using version sort, is already posted here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write custom filter, e.g.

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/filter.py 
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

def version_sort(l):
    return sorted(l, key=LooseVersion)

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters for operating on versions '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'version_sort' : version_sort,
            }
```

Given the list

```yaml
  l:
  - pl2
  - pl2.10
  - pl2.100
  - pl2.102
  - pl2.11
  - pl2.111
```

the sorting works as expected

```yaml
  l|version_sort:
  - pl2
  - pl2.10
  - pl2.11
  - pl2.100
  - pl2.102
  - pl2.111
```